# Powershell output -Join comma

Tags: powershell, scripting

Hi there i have a script which prints me member of a specific group. But the output doesent satisfy me.

My Code so far:

```
$ADGroup = Get-ADGroup $Id -Properties member | Select-Object -ExpandProperty member
                    Write-Output "`n" | Out-File $Log -append
                   
                   
                    
                    $UserList += Write-Output "Member of $Id :
                    "
                    foreach ($Object in $ADGroup)
                        {
                            $Group      = Get-ADUser -filter * -SearchBase "$Object"
                            if($Group -ne $null)
                                {
                                    $GrName     = $Group.samaccountname
                                    $UserList += $GrName
                                }
                                
                                
                        }
```

I get output like:

Member of

name1

name2

etc...

but i want it to be name1, name2

Answer (score 0):

Okay i solved it myself.

Just added `", "` to `$UserList += $GrName`

Comment: But this way the last element of the list also get a ",". So if someone got a better idea tell me :)